# FQL returns "Requires valid signature"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am having a wierd problem, things that worked before stopped working today, maybe it was bad before but now after the oAUTH 2 change, I am having troubles with a near production app

this is what I try

```
$params = array('method'=>'fql.query','query' => 'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()');
$result =  $facebook->api($params);
```

I get:

```
Exception: 104: Requires valid signature
```

or more elaborated :

```
$config = array(
'appId'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$uid = $facebook->getUser();

if ($uid){
 try {
        $access_t = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $fql = 'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = '.$uid;
        $params = array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => 'SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = '.$uid);
        $result = $facebook->api($params);
        echo $result;
        $friends = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $fql, 'access_token' => $access_t));
        var_dump($friends);

 } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo $e; 
 }
```

this is the code I am using to validate the user and get the login info and permissions allowed:

```
$canvas_base_url = "https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/index.php?from=allow";
$params = array('scope' => 'publish_stream,email,offline_access,user_status,friends_status,friends_photos,user_photos,xmpp_login,user_online_presence,friends_online_presence',
'redirect_uri' => $canvas_base_url
);
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means the access token you are using is invalid. It has probably expired.

Here's a quote from the docs at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/:

> In addition to the access token (the access_token parameter), the
>   response contains the number of seconds until the token expires (the
>   expires parameter). Once the token expires, you will need to re-run
>   the steps above to generate a new code and access_token, although if
>   the user has already authorized your app, they will not be prompted to
>   do so again. If your app needs an access token with an infinite expiry
>   time (perhaps to take actions on the user's behalf after they are not
>   using your app), you can request the offline_access permission.

So you should re-run the steps to generate an access token, or require the offline_access permission.